# Gradle, SonarQube plugin and project names with illegal characters

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

We have a multi-project gradle build, which organizes the projects into directories. Example:

```
root
+--Libraries
   +-- Project1
   +-- Project2
+--Tools
   +-- Project3
   +-- Project4
```

Since the SonarRunner plugin is deprecated, we have attempted to use the official [SonarQube plugin for gradle](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle). The gradle version used is 2.10.

Due to our project structure, there are problems with the project names: SonarQube plugin receives projects names "Libraries\Project1". "\" is an illegal character for a project name.

Previously, for SonarRunner, the problem was fixed by overriding the ProjectKey property:

```
// project specific sonar configuration
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
  subprojects {
    sonarRunner {
      sonarProperties {
        def projectKey = "$project.group:$project.name".replaceAll('/', '-')
        property 'sonar.projectKey', projectKey
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The equivalent tried for SonarQube is

```
// project specific sonar configuration
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
  subprojects {
    sonarqube{
      properties {
        def projectKey = "$project.group:$project.name".replaceAll('/', '-')
        property 'sonar.projectKey', projectKey
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work with SonarQube. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, on a Linux environment, was to replace a '/' with ':', and to override the moduleKey. Add this part in your root build.gradle file:

subprojects {

```
sonarqube {
    String regex = "(.*)/(.*)"
    String projectKey = project.name.replaceAll(regex, "\$1:\$2")
    String sonarModuleKey = rootProject.group + ':' + rootProject.name + ':' + projectKey

    properties {
        property "sonar.moduleKey", sonarModuleKey
    }
}
```

}